# Formatting of JavaScript Objects, Showing Sub Products under Products

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects for products I want to show objects that have a parent ID under their parent object with property called subproduct

I have a array object like

```
let products = [{
        "id": 30,
        "service_provider_id": 4,
        "parent_id": null,
        "status_id": 1,
        "code": "1450",
        "name": "Paypal"
    },
    {
        "id": 31,
        "service_provider_id": 4,
        "parent_id": 30,
        "status_id": 1,
        "code": "1451",
        "name": "Payments"
    }
]
```

**I want to format it in the following way**

```
"products": [{
    "id": 30,
    "service_provider_id": 4,
    "parent_id": null,
    "status_id": 1,
    "code": "14",
    "name": "Paypal"
    "sub-products": [{
        "id": 31,
        "service_provider_id": 4,
        "parent_id": 30,
        "status_id": 1,
        "code": "15",
        "name": "Paypal-Payments"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: @radarbob formatted it, do you have an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```js
let products =  [
  {
      "id": 30,
      "service_provider_id": 4,
      "parent_id": null,
      "status_id": 1,
      "code": "1450",
      "name": "Paypal"
  },
  {
      "id": 31,
      "service_provider_id": 4,
      "parent_id": 30,
      "status_id": 1,
      "code": "1451",
      "name": "Payments"
  }
]

let formated = [];

formated = products.filter(product => product.parent_id == null);

formated.forEach(formatedproduct=>{
  products.forEach(product =>{
      if(product.parent_id == formatedproduct.id){
        if(!formatedproduct.sub_products )
        {
        formatedproduct.sub_products = [];
        }
        product.name = formatedproduct.name +' '+product.name;
        formatedproduct.sub_products.push(product);
        
        
      }
  });
})

console.log(formated);
```

Comment: thank you please add this line below the subproduct assignment and i will accept your answer formatedproduct.sub_products[0].name = formatedproduct.name + ' ' +product.name;

Comment: Check it out  I have made some changes

Comment: This assumes that there are no more than two levels of products.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of map and reduce

```js
const grouped = [
    ...products
        .sort((a, b) => a.parent_id - b.parent_id)
        .reduce((a, b) => a.set(b.parent_id || b.id, (a.get(b.parent_id) || []).concat(b)), new Map())
        .values()
]
    .map(([f, ...rest]) => (f.sub_products = rest, f));

console.log(grouped);
```

```html
<script>
  const products = [{
      'id': 30,
      'service_provider_id': 4,
      'parent_id': null,
      'status_id': 1,
      'code': '1450',
      'name': 'Paypal'
    },
    {
      'id': 31,
      'service_provider_id': 4,
      'parent_id': 30,
      'status_id': 1,
      'code': '1451',
      'name': 'Payments'
    },
    {
      'id': 32,
      'service_provider_id': 4,
      'parent_id': null,
      'status_id': 1,
      'code': '1450',
      'name': 'Paypal'
    },
    {
      'id': 33,
      'service_provider_id': 4,
      'parent_id': 32,
      'status_id': 1,
      'code': '1451',
      'name': 'Payments'
    }
  ];
</script>
```